# ILP relaxation for Cluster deletion on C5

Tags: graphs, integer-programming, clique

I'm looking for additional constraints that get rid of fractional solutions for the LP relaxation of the Cluster Deletion problem:

Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, find a min. sized $E' \subset E$ s.t. the induced graph with edge set $E-E'$ is a cluster graph, i.e. one in which all connected components are cliques.

An ILP formulation is:

$$max \sum_{(u,v) \in E)} x_{uv}$$

subject to:

$$ x_{uv} + x_{vw} - x_{uw} \leq 1$$
$$ \forall (u,v) \in E: x_{uv} \in\{0,1\}$$
$$ \forall (u,v) \notin E: x_{uv} = 0$$

Looking at the 5-cycle graph I showed that the optimal solution is never integral and now I have to provide additional constraints (for the 5 cycle graph) which forbid non-integral solutions, but I'm unable to come up with any. Can someone help here please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  Is this problem NP-hard?  (I presume it is.)  If so, there is not likely to be any polynomial set of constraints that prevent non-integral solutions; if there was, it would lead to a polynomial-time algorithm (since linear programming can be solved in polynomial time) and thus a proof that P = NP, which seems a bit much to expect.

Comment: I haven't seen a proof, but I also presume that the problem is NP-hard. The number of constraints doesn't have to be polynomial.

Comment: Note that the additional constraints are only needed for the 5-cycle graph.

Comment: If you only want it to work for a single graph, then it's trivial: find the solution somehow, then add constraints that force each $x_{uv}$ to be either 0 or 1 according to whether it is in that solution.  Is this a homework exercise?  What's the context in which you encountered this problem?